# Why is Joker more powerful than other users?

Tags: fire-force

Joker, as a second generation user, is actually very powerful more than others of his generation.

As I understand, the "skills" acquired by second generation users depend on the person. In the case of Joker, he uses the cigars as a source of the fire.

Does this imply that other users can "copy" these techniques? Or is he different?

Comment: Yes, this is the serie.

Comment: I don't know nothing about the name "Fire Force", but okey thank you for create a tag for this manga.

Comment: According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%82%8E%E7%82%8E%E3%83%8E%E6%B6%88%E9%98%B2%E9%9A%8A#.E3.81.9D.E3.81.AE.E3.81.BB.E3.81.8B), Joker's generation is unclear. May I know where did it say that he's a second generation user? Apart from that, there's not much information regarding him other than "a mysterious person"